# How to change the default terminal in Manjaro?

Tags: terminal, manjaro

I recently switched from ubuntu to Manjaro. On ubuntu I used [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) and made it my default terminal emulator.

I did so with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Is there a way to set the default terminal emulator with Manjaro/Arch?

**Edit:**
I'm using Manjaro Gnome

Comment: You can use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1454287/89497) replacing "kgx" with "tilix" – tested successfully on Manjaro GNOME 43.

Answer (score 8):

I currently use manjaro (i3), and in the past have used manjaro preloaded with different desktop environments(gnome, xfce and KDE). One thing that I have observed is that the default terminal emulator depends on the preloaded desktop environment. Unfortunately, you have not provided which DE you use.

- For gnome, you can execute:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal`

  Make sure to replace gnome-terminal with your choice.
- If you use xfce DE, then go to settings, then preferred application, then utilities tab and then change the terminal emulator from there.
- If you use i3, you can either change the i3 config file located in ~/.i3/ and then change the binding for $mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal (Replace i3-sensible-terminal with your choice.) OR you can install xfce4-settings-manager using:

  `sudo pacman -S xfce4-settings`

  Then execute xfce4-settings-manager using menu ($mod+d) follow the steps as I mentioned for xfce desktop environment above.

Comment: I'm using Manjaro Gnome. I just tried the above mentioned suggestion, I don't think it works for me. Also, when I check `org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal` in *dconf*, it says in the description: `Terminal program to use when starting applications that require one. DEPRECATED: This key is deprecated and ignored. The default terminal is handled in GIO.`

Comment: I added my current "solution" as separate answer for others, but it's just a work-around

Comment: Try this (2 commands one by one)

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec /usr/bin/terminator`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec-arg "-x"`

Comment: You forgot to mention an option for KDE users :(

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution, but a work-around that works for most of my use cases.

Adding a keyboard shortcut (under Settings → Devices → Keyboard) with:

Name: `Launch Terminal`
Command: `tilix`
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: `which tilix` **tilix not found**

Comment: you need to install tilix (https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on KDE:

I am currently using Manjaro with **KDE** version 5.26.4. For me I went into **Settings --> Applications --> Default Applications**.
From there you can select the **Terminal emulator** of your choice from the drop-down menu.